# Calculate difference of 2 dates in a pandas groupby object of the same 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-datetime, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a new `pandas.DataFrame` column of the number of business days between two date columns. I'm unable to reference the dates in the date columns as arguments in a function call (I get a TypeError: Cannot convert input error). However, I'm able to zip the values in the series into a List and use a For Loop to reference the parameters. Ideally, I would prefer to create a GroupBy object from the two Date columns and calculate the difference.

#### Create DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date1': ['2017-05-30 16:00:00',
  '2017-05-30 16:00:00',
  '2017-05-30 16:00:00'],
 'Date2': ['2017-06-16 16:00:00',
  '2017-07-21 16:00:00',
  '2017-08-18 16:00:00'],
 'Value1': [2.97, 3.3, 4.03],
 'Value2': [96L, 14L, 2L]})

df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])

df.dtypes
```

#### Validate DataFrame:

```
Date1     datetime64[ns]
Date2     datetime64[ns]
Value1           float64
Value2             int64
dtype: object
```

#### Define function:

```
def date_diff(startDate, endDate):
    return float(len(pd.bdate_range(startDate, endDate)) - 1)
```

#### Attempt to column from the result of the date_diff function call:

```
df['DateDiff'] = date_diff(df['Date1'], df['Date2'])
```

#### TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [0   2017-05-30 16:00:00
1   2017-05-30 16:00:00
2   2017-05-30 16:00:00
Name: Date1, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

#### A "For Loop" referencing a list of tuples containing the dates works:

```
date_List = list(zip(df['Date1'], df['Date2']))

for i in range(len(date_List)):
    df.loc[(df['Date1'] == date_List[i][0]) & (df['Date2'] == date_List[i][1]), 'diff'] = date_diff(date_List[i][0], date_List[i][1])

                Date1               Date2  Value1  Value2  diff
0 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-06-16 16:00:00    2.97      96  13.0
1 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-07-21 16:00:00    3.30      14  38.0
2 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-08-18 16:00:00    4.03       2  58.0
```

#### Ideally, I'd like to utilize a GroupBy object (by Date1 & Date2):

```
grp = df.groupby(['Date1', 'Date2'])
```

#### Desired Output:

```
[((Timestamp('2017-05-30 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-06-16 16:00:00')),
                  Date1               Date2  Value1  Value2  diff
  0 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-06-16 16:00:00    2.97      96  13.0),
 ((Timestamp('2017-05-30 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-07-21 16:00:00')),
                  Date1               Date2  Value1  Value2  diff
  1 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-07-21 16:00:00     3.3      14  38.0),
 ((Timestamp('2017-05-30 16:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-18 16:00:00')),
                  Date1               Date2  Value1  Value2  diff
  2 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-08-18 16:00:00    4.03       2  58.0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type cast to `datetime64[D]` to make numpy happy like:

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np

def date_diff(start_dates, end_dates):
    return np.busday_count(
        start_dates.values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
        end_dates.values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date1': ['2017-05-30 16:00:00',
                                       '2017-05-30 16:00:00',
                                       '2017-05-30 16:00:00'],
                             'Date2': ['2017-06-16 16:00:00',
                                       '2017-07-21 16:00:00',
                                       '2017-08-18 16:00:00'],
                             'Value1': [2.97, 3.3, 4.03],
                             'Value2': [96L, 14L, 2L]})

df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])

df['DateDiff'] = date_diff(df['Date1'], df['Date2'])
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
                Date1               Date2  Value1  Value2  DateDiff
0 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-06-16 16:00:00    2.97      96        13
1 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-07-21 16:00:00    3.30      14        38
2 2017-05-30 16:00:00 2017-08-18 16:00:00    4.03       2        58
```